# Flexslider Responsiveness

Tags: image, responsive-design, flexslider

Just wondered if anyone using the Flexslider has found that when switching back and forth from different size browser windows the slide images do not automatically adjust to new height and widths.

Let me clarify - they do shrink correctly but when scaling back up the first image in the slideshow gets stuck at the previous aspect ratio until the next slide comes in, at which point the whole thing adjusts.

To stop my content from being affected I have created a fixed height container for the flexslider and have used media queries to change its height as it is scaled down. This works perfectly scaling down.

It seems to be on the way back up that it has trouble sorting the image heights out.

I would provide links but it is a new client project in confidence.

All coding is exactly as is from the demo files, with exception to the fixed height and media queries on the container div.

Comment: what browser are you in? never noticed a problem. are you using flex slider 2? does it do it on their demo page: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: Hi Matt, I am checking all browsers but my main one is Firefox. It is a customised version but it is Flexslider 2. It isn't a major issue.

Take a look here: www.aspectexhibitions.co.uk/wordpress-test

Comment: Im not seeing anything on Chrome, Safari or Firefox (OSX versions) all seems well...Im really curious though you should do a screencast of it.

Comment: Not to worry it would be difficult to show you as I am testing across different devices in the office. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

I had the SAME problem - I found that not all my widths were of the same value.

e.g.

```
.clone  { display: block; float: left; width: 994px!important; }


<img src="http://www.website.com/images/panel1.jpg" alt="" width="980px">
```

There were about 4 instances in my css that had different widths [shame shame] so I went in there and raked the css file.

I hope this helps

Good Luck